# Unexpected '@' in xcode after upgrade of xcode

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

Can someone help me out with why this error showed up after I upgraded to the newest version of xcode? The app was working fine prior to this, but this syntax error prevents compiling now. I am getting the error at 
`#pragma mark -@property (nonatomic, k Constants`, 
and also I get a missing `@end` error.

Sorry for posting the entire page, but I wanted to make sure I provided enough to get assistance.

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface MBProgressHUD ()

(void)hideUsingAnimation:(BOOL)animated;
(void)showUsingAnimation:(BOOL)animated;

(void)fillRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context;

(void)done;
(void)updateLabelText:(NSString *)newText;
(void)updateDetailsLabelText:(NSString *)newText;
(void)updateProgress;
(void)updateIndicators;

(void)handleGraceTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer;
(void)handleMinShowTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer;

@property (retain) UIView *indicator;

@property (assign) float width;
@property (assign) float height;

@property (retain) NSTimer *graceTimer;
@property (retain) NSTimer *minShowTimer;

@property (retain) NSDate *showStarted;

@end


@implementation MBProgressHUD

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Accessors

@synthesize mode;

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize labelText;
@synthesize detailsLabelText;
@synthesize opacity;
@synthesize labelFont;
@synthesize detailsLabelFont;
@synthesize progress;

@synthesize indicator;

@synthesize width;
@synthesize height;
@synthesize xOffset;
@synthesize yOffset;

@synthesize graceTime;
@synthesize minShowTime;
@synthesize graceTimer;
@synthesize minShowTimer;
@synthesize taskInProgress;

@synthesize showStarted;

(void)setMode:(MBProgressHUDMode)newMode {

if (mode && (mode == newMode)) {
return;
}

mode = newMode;

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateIndicators) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsLayout) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

(void)setLabelText:(NSString *)newText {
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabelText:) withObject:newText waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsLayout) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

(void)setDetailsLabelText:(NSString *)newText {
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateDetailsLabelText:) withObject:newText waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsLayout) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

(void)setProgress:(float)newProgress {
progress = newProgress;

if (mode == MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate) {
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgress) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Accessor helpers

(void)updateLabelText:(NSString *)newText {
if (labelText != newText) {
[labelText release];
labelText = [newText copy];
}
}

(void)updateDetailsLabelText:(NSString *)newText {
if (detailsLabelText != newText) {
[detailsLabelText release];
detailsLabelText = [newText copy];
}
}

(void)updateProgress {
[(MBRoundProgressView *)indicator setProgress:progress];
}

(void)updateIndicators {
if (indicator) {
[indicator removeFromSuperview];
}

self.indicator = nil;

if (mode == MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate) {
self.indicator = [[MBRoundProgressView alloc] initWithDefaultSize];
}
else {
self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[(UIActivityIndicatorView *)indicator startAnimating];
}

[self addSubview:indicator];
}

**#pragma mark -
@property (nonatomic, k Constants**

#define MARGIN 20.0
#define PADDING 4.0

#define LABELFONTSIZE 22.0
#define LABELDETAILSFONTSIZE 16.0

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Lifecycle methods

(id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
@property (nonatomic, nonatomic, nonatomic, [self initWithView:window];
}

(id)initWithView:(UIView *)view {
initializer above)
if (!view) {
@property (nonatomic, ion raise:@"MBProgressHUDViewIsNillException"
format:@"The view used in the MBProgressHUD initializer is nil."];
}
return [self initWithFrame:view.bounds];
}

(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

self.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
self.labelText = nil;
self.detailsLabelText = nil;
self.opacity = 0.9;
self.labelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:LABELFONTSIZE];
self.detailsLabelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:LABELDETAILSFONTSIZE];
self.xOffset = 0.0;
self.yOffset = 0.0;
self.graceTime = 0.0;
self.minShowTime = 0.0;

self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;


self.opaque = NO;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.alpha = 0.0;


label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];


detailsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];

taskInProgress = NO;
}
return self;
}

(void)dealloc {
[indicator release];
[label release];
[detailsLabel release];
[labelText release];
[detailsLabelText release];
[graceTimer release];
[minShowTimer release];
[showStarted release];
[super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Layout

(void)layoutSubviews {
CGRect frame = self.bounds;


@property (nonatomic, indFrame = indicator.bounds;
self.width = indFrame.size.width + 2 * MARGIN;
self.height = indFrame.size.height + 2 * MARGIN;


indFrame.origin.x = floor((frame.size.width - indFrame.size.width) / 2) + self.xOffset;
indFrame.origin.y = floor((frame.size.height - indFrame.size.height) / 2) + self.yOffset;
indicator.frame = indFrame;


if (nil != self.labelText) {

CGSize dims = [self.labelText sizeWithFont:self.labelFont];

clip the label width
float lHeight = dims.height;
float lWidth;
if (dims.width <= (frame.size.width - 2 * MARGIN)) {
lWidth = dims.width;
}
else {
lWidth = frame.size.width - 4 * MARGIN;
}

label.font = self.labelFont;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.opaque = NO;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = self.labelText;

if (self.width < (lWidth + 2 * MARGIN)) {
self.width = lWidth + 2 * MARGIN;
}
self.height = self.height + lHeight + PADDING;


indFrame.origin.y -= (floor(lHeight / 2 + PADDING / 2));
indicator.frame = indFrame;

// Set the label position and dimensions
CGRect lFrame = CGRectMake(floor((frame.size.width - lWidth) / 2) + xOffset,
floor(indFrame.origin.y + indFrame.size.height + PADDING),
lWidth, lHeight);
label.frame = lFrame;

[self addSubview:label];

// Add details label delatils text was set
if (nil != self.detailsLabelText) {
// Get size of label text
dims = [self.detailsLabelText sizeWithFont:self.detailsLabelFont];

// Compute label dimensions based on font metrics if size is larger than max then clip the label width
lHeight = dims.height;
if (dims.width <= (frame.size.width - 2 * MARGIN)) {
lWidth = dims.width;
}
else {
lWidth = frame.size.width - 4 * MARGIN;
}

// Set label properties
detailsLabel.font = self.detailsLabelFont;
detailsLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
detailsLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
detailsLabel.opaque = NO;
detailsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
detailsLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
detailsLabel.text = self.detailsLabelText;

// Update HUD size
if (self.width < lWidth) {
self.width = lWidth + 2 * MARGIN;
}
self.height = self.height + lHeight + PADDING;
// Move indicator to make room for the new label
indFrame.origin.y -= (floor(lHeight / 2 + PADDING / 2));
indicator.frame = indFrame;

// Move first label to make room for the new label
lFrame.origin.y -= (floor(lHeight / 2 + PADDING / 2));
label.frame = lFrame;

// Set label position and dimensions
CGRect lFrameD = CGRectMake(floor((frame.size.width - lWidth) / 2) + xOffset,
lFrame.origin.y + lFrame.size.height + PADDING, lWidth, lHeight);
detailsLabel.frame = lFrameD;

[self addSubview:detailsLabel];
}
}
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Showing and execution

- (void)show:(BOOL)animated {
useAnimation = animated;

// If the grace time is set postpone the HUD display
if (self.graceTime > 0.0) {
self.graceTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.graceTime
target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(handleGraceTimer:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:NO];
}
// ... otherwise show the HUD imediately
else {
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[self showUsingAnimation:useAnimation];
}
}

- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated {
useAnimation = animated;

// If the minShow time is set, calculate how long the hud was shown,
// and pospone the hiding operation if necessary
if (self.minShowTime > 0.0 && showStarted) {
NSTimeInterval interv = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:showStarted];
if (interv < self.minShowTime) {
self.minShowTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(self.minShowTime - interv)
target:self
                                                               selector:@selector(handleMinShowTimer:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:NO];
return;
}
}

// ... otherwise hide the HUD immediately
[self hideUsingAnimation:useAnimation];
}

- (void)handleGraceTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
// Show the HUD only if the task is still running
if (taskInProgress) {
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[self showUsingAnimation:useAnimation];
}
}

- (void)handleMinShowTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
[self hideUsingAnimation:useAnimation];
}

- (void)showWhileExecuting:(SEL)method onTarget:(id)target withObject:(id)object animated:(BOOL)animated {

methodForExecution = method;
targetForExecution = [target retain];
objectForExecution = [object retain];

// Launch execution in new thread
taskInProgress = YES;
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(launchExecution) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

// Show HUD view
[self show:animated];
}

- (void)launchExecution {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// Start executing the requested task
[targetForExecution performSelector:methodForExecution withObject:objectForExecution];

// Task completed, update view in main thread (note: view operations should
// be done only in the main thread)
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(cleanUp) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

[pool release];
}

- (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void*)context {
[self done];
}

- (void)done {
isFinished = YES;

// If delegate was set make the callback
self.alpha = 0.0;

if(delegate != nil && [delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MBProgressHUDDelegate)]) {
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(hudWasHidden)]) {
[delegate performSelector:@selector(hudWasHidden)];
}
}
}

- (void)cleanUp {
taskInProgress = NO;

self.indicator = nil;

[targetForExecution release];
[objectForExecution release];

[self hide:useAnimation];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fade in and Fade out

- (void)showUsingAnimation:(BOOL)animated {
self.showStarted = [NSDate date];
// Fade in
if (animated) {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.40];
self.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
else {
self.alpha = 1.0;
}
}

- (void)hideUsingAnimation:(BOOL)animated {
// Fade out
if (animated) {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.40];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished: finished: context:)];
// 0.02 prevents the hud from passing through touches during the animation the hud will get completely hidden
// in the done method
self.alpha = 0.02;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
else {
self.alpha = 0.0;
[self done];
}
}

#pragma mark BG Drawing

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Center HUD
CGRect allRect = self.bounds;
// Draw rounded HUD bacgroud rect
CGRect boxRect = CGRectMake(((allRect.size.width - self.width) / 2) + self.xOffset,
                                ((allRect.size.height - self.height) / 2) + self.yOffset, self.width, self.height);
CGContextRef ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self fillRoundedRect:boxRect inContext:ctxt];
}

- (void)fillRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
float radius = 10.0f;

CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 0.0, self.opacity);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect) - radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, 0, M_PI / 2, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, M_PI, 0);
CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect) + radius, CGRectGetMinY(rect) + radius, radius, M_PI, 3 * M_PI / 2, 0);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
}

@end


@implementation MBRoundProgressView

- (id)initWithDefaultSize {
return [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 37.0f, 37.0f)];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGRect allRect = self.bounds;
CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(allRect.origin.x + 2, allRect.origin.y + 2, allRect.size.width - 4,
allRect.size.height - 4);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Draw background
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // white
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1); // translucent white
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);

// Draw progress
float x = (allRect.size.width / 2);
float y = (allRect.size.height / 2);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // white
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
CGContextAddArc(context, x, y, (allRect.size.width - 4) / 2, -(PI / 2), (self.progress * 2 * PI) - PI / 2, 0);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
}

@end
```

Comment: At which line numbers? And perhaps you can provide the header file as well, if you want to include everything.

Comment: It also helps if you only include the relevant information rather than your entire source file.

Answer (score 0):

The line throwing the error makes no sense.

```
#pragma mark -
@property (nonatomic, k Constants
```

the `#pragma mark -` puts a line in the drop down list but what is the next line supposed to do?

if you are declaring a property, then you haven't closed the bracket after `nonatomic`, but when what is `k Constants` supposed to be. Are you sure you didn't change the file?

Comment: When I upgraded to the newest version of xcode, it converted everything for iOS 6 support. After it did that, it started throwing this error

Comment: Are you thinking this auto convert xcode did erased something?

Comment: No - I'm thinking that the line I mentioned doesn't make sense. You could just try fixing it.